# API Keys with Google Maps Geocoding

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am using JQuery to get JSON data from the Google Maps Geodcode API using:

```
var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sydney&key=MY-KEY";

$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The documentation says I require a Server API Key, but this is not server side code?

I tried making a Server API Key using my own routers IP address and it worked (but of course this is useless for any other users). I tried adding the web hosts IP and just got the error that the key is not authorised.

I know you can run it without a key for small quotas, but is that not advisable?

Would anyone know how to make this work? Do I have to do this in server side with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation from Google in [Issue 4921: Bug: missing CORS HTTP Header](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4921) is:

> You should really be using the Javascript client library. We are intentionally not setting CORS headers on this geocode service, as it is intended to be used by servers.
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

If you are going to be using the geocoding service from javascript on the client use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) with a **browser** key.

Comment: Ah so Geocoding is part of the JS API as well as it's own stand-alone API?

Comment: Yes.  There are examples in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)